Update IAM role to add Error Report Writer
Sorry for posting this...
I am having lots of issues with my error reporting, my latest troubleshooting has me adding the role of roles/errorreporting.writer but when I go to the IAM page, click on the email address for the service account, then click Permissions, then click Grant Access, then click add role, nothing at all comes up for error at all?

What am I missing, why am I unable to add new role for Error report writer?

Not a programming question and so likely to be down-voted/closed. I would have expected Error Reporting roles to be granted to a Service Account. The page in your question appears to be used for granting a Service Account and Role Bindings to a resource type (that presumably does not permit it).

Thanks is there a way to update the role of the service account, I cannot seem to find it anywhere. I'm glad I have stackoverflow point to spend. Any suggestions are well appreciated.

Glad you solved it. Apologies for not replying sooner; I was eating.

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
I was looking under
console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts
Thanks for the comment Daz!
